# Reindex from host with sphinx docker container

Tags: sphinx, docker, thinking-sphinx

Just want ask a clarifying question before I pursue docker further here.  I'm trying to understand the life cycle of indices with Sphinx in a container.

Provided I set up a container with Sphinx with [some build](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/leodido/sphinxsearch/), so it has some shared indices, how can I reindex from the host?  Will I have to determine the container IP (assuming through $CID) and then send the reindex command through SSH to the container or something else fancy manner?

I'm using Rails with thinking sphinx and have some nice capistrano hooks to reindex from my dev box, I'm guessing I'm going to loose those by putting sphinx in a docker container since sphinx would no longer be on the host itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A container is just like a virtual machine with an added advantage that it is much lighter. So you can do the re-indexing any manner you like or do. Either `ssh` or directly through the bash shell you receive when you run the container from the provided image.